# C++11 lambda capture `this` and capture local variables by value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The lambda function below captures `this` (so `bar()` can access its instance vars) and the local variables `a,b,c`.

```
class Foo {
  int x, y, z;
  std::function<void(void)> _func;
  // ...
  void bar() {
     int a,b,c;
     // ...
     _func = [this,a,b,c]() { // lambda func
        int u = this->x + a;
        // ...
     };
  }
};
```

But if I want to capture many instance variables and wish to avoid explicitly naming them in the capture list, I do *not* seem to be able to do this:

```
     _func = [this,=]() { // lambda func
        // ...
     };
```

I get a compiler error at the `=` following `this,`:

```
  error: expected variable name or 'this' in lambda capture list
```

If I try this

```
     _func = [=,this]() { // lambda func
        // ...
     };
```

I get

```
  error: 'this' cannot be explicitly captured when the capture default is '='
```

Is there a shorthand for capturing `this` and everything else by value?

**UPDATE:** `[=, this]` as a lambda capture is a [new feature of C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20)

Comment: Doesn't `[=]` capture `this` aswell?

Comment: Really? By golly it does. I guess I'll erase my question.

Comment: I guess SO wants me to keep the question here ... maybe some other poor programming soul (e.g., a Swift programmer who use used to `[unowned self]`) will find it useful.

Comment: [this,=] would have been a confusing oxymoron, because this is a pointer to object..sooo effectively you would capture whole object by reference, which conflicts with the default by value [=].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As cppreference says:

> [=] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current object by reference if exists

Comment: Evident `[=,this]` added in C++20. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20

Answer (score 6):

`[=]` does what you want -- it captures anything not a member variable by value, and `*this` by reference (or `this` by value).

`[*this,=]` captures both local variables *and* the object by value in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

`[&]` captures local variables by reference and `*this` by reference or `this` (the pointer) by value.

Both default capture modes capture `this` the same way.  Only in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) can you change that.

Answer (score 3):

`[=]` already captures `this` by value. Take a look at the following code live here: http://cpp.sh/87iw6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string text;

    auto printer() {
        return [=]() {
            std::cout << this->text << "\n";
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    auto printer = a.printer();
    a.text = "Hello, world!";

    printer();
}
```

Comment: `this` is the current object and is captured by reference, isn't it?

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the current object, which is captured by reference. Capturing  the `this` pointer is effectively capturing the object by reference.

Comment: Yes, that's why I find your statement "... already captures this by value" misleading.

Comment: I don't since `this` is a pointer and that's how copying pointers by value works.

Answer (score 2):

`[=]` will work, because it captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy.

Here is the example output: https://www.ideone.com/kkXvJT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
  int x, y, z;
  std::function<void(void)> _func;

public:
  Foo(int a): x(a), y(0), z(0)  {}

  void bar()
  {
    int a = 1,b,c;
    _func = [=]()
    {
      int u = this->x + a;
      std::cout << u << std::endl;
    };

    _func(); // lambda call
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo obj(1);
  obj.bar();
}
```